# The fastest reputation points gaining user at Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics

How do I determine which user is moving at the fastest pace in terms of reputation points?

I am asking for users who have been at Stack Overflow for at least five months. Any query to be run at Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), any script, how do I know that?

Comment: Don't even ask about first. Maybe not second either. There's really no point...

Comment: @dmckee: Actually it could be used to create a list of users with crazy high rep gains which might be falsified.

Comment: By contrast, if you count gaining negative rep, I'd say that Evan Carroll has sewn up the fastest overall change rate on MSO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jon Skeet.

See [this SE Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/946/rising-stars-top-50-users-ordered-on-rep-per-day) (not by me).

Comment: Interesting, although it's fundamentally based on a different range for every user.  Would be more interesting to see this summarized over a specific time period (i.e. last 3 months).  I'll bet that the results are at least a lot closer, especially considering that there was no rep cap in the early days.

Comment: @Aarobot: The rep cap has been applied retrospectively (and there's always been one since I joined).

Comment: Query no longer works.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine that user would be Jon Skeet, the answer to life, the universe, and everything.

<sub><sup>(hope I got the quote right)</sup></sub>

Comment: I doubt that he has the current highest first derivative.

Comment: @Rosinante: I suspect I have, actually. Generally on a week day I earn between 260 and 350 rep... I haven't seen any other users with quite that rate. I've seen some close, don't get me wrong... and I certainly wouldn't claim to earn the most on every single day... but I suspect over any given month I may well have the highest rep.

Comment: The "any tag" stats page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=&sort=stats&pagesize=50 - it *somewhat* indicative, but it doesn't take into account the rep cap, just votes.

Comment: @Jon oh, well, wrong again.

Answer (score 2):

I would say Jon Skeet because a while ago he made a Twitter update saying "Wow today is the first day in months I didn't hit the reputation cap on Stack Overflow".